How should I make a slider to select part of a video in react native?

It's a draggable double ended slider that has the selected part of a video.
Should I use @react-native-community/slider and overlay?
Also for the video should I generate a couple of images using ffmpeg and combine them to have them as the background?
What's the best way that I can achive this?
